# How can I Lock a Cell Range based on Time via VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to lock a specific range of cells (B2:B40) after it passing time 10:01 AM every day.
The code I'm using is:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
    If Time > #10:01:00 AM# Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="125487"
        Range("B2:B40").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
```

But It doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

Comment: When does it unlock? When the workbook is closed? It takes a few minutes to bypass excel security so what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: The value in the cell range shouldn't be changed, doesn't matter is it empty or with values. It has to be locked everyday between 10:01 and 17:30. The unlocking in this time period should it be thru password.

Comment: When you say `But it doesn't work`.. what does that mean? you have to be more specific (i.e. workbook doesn't lock, code throws an error on this line)

Comment: I assume that you have other scripts that run at other times to set the password of the sheet and unlock the cells? if not, the passwords will need to be set the same and the cells would need to be unlocked for this to be of any use. Make sure your code is added to the ThisWorkbook in your VBA Project. Instead of ActiveSheet, define the actual sheet names for both the .unprotect and .locked. and dont forget to add the end sub. It worked for me when testing.

Comment: If the workbook is already open prior to 10:01, then they will be able to edit the cell.

Comment: Yes, the workbook is opend in 8:30, and I need a code witch will locked it in 10:01h to 17:30h. But my code is not doing it! I hope that now I am more cleard of what I need. :) Thank you! :)

Comment: For future reference, please be very clear when asking questions, you had said that you wanted cells to be unlocked after a certain time, then in your code you was using the workbook_open, so any answers were relating to a problem with the code not running when the workbook was opened after a defined time. When really you should have mentioned in your original question what you really want to happen, in this case the workbook will be open but then you want it to lock cells at some point in time whilst still open. To help you out I have posted an answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I apologize for my equivocally asked (not determined) questions, but I'm still new to the VBA encoding. I still have to learn a lot of information and I really appreciate your help. The code is working, I test it today and it's superr! :)
I promisse in future to be more clear, when I'm asking questions.
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be very specific setting the references to the actual workbook and sheet, try something like:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Dim sys_time As String
Dim wb_password As String

sys_time = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
wb_password = "125487"

If TimeValue(sys_time) > TimeValue("10:01:00") Then

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    .Unprotect Password:=wb_password
    .Range("B2:B40").Locked = True
    .Protect Password:=wb_password

End With

ThisWorkbook.Save

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your workbook open and you would like it to lock the cells whilst open, you can use Application.OnTime.

In your VBA Project copy this code into ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Dim CurrTime As Date
Dim LockTime As Date
Dim UnLockTime As Date

CurrTime = Time ' Get the Current Time
LockTime = "10:01:00" ' Specify the Lock Time
UnLockTime = "17:30:00" ' Specify the Unlock Time

     If TimeValue(CurrTime) > UnLockTime Then ' If the sheet is opened later than the specified unlock time then we want make sure the cells are unlocked.

            Application.Run "UnLockSheet"

     Else

        If TimeValue(CurrTime) < LockTime Then ' Check to see if the sheet is opened before the lock time

            ' When the sheet is open, before the LockTime, we need to make sure the cells are unlocked    
            Application.Run "UnLockSheet"

            ' Then we can set a timer to run to lock the cells at the defined time. 
            Application.OnTime LockTime - CurrTime + Now, "LockSheet"

            Else

                ' This will automaticly Lock the cells if opened after the Lock time but before the unlock time
                Application.Run "LockSheet"

                ' If opened after the Lock time but before the unlock time, the timer will need to start, ready to unlock the cells at the specified time
                Application.OnTime UnLockTime - CurrTime + Now, "UnLockSheet"

        End If

     End If

End Sub
```

And add these scripts to a Module in your VBAProject:

```
Sub LockSheet()

    ' This will lock the cells

    ' Specify the exact sheet name otherwise whichever sheet is active, will have cells unlocked and a password set
    ' I would also specify the workbook name to prevent any other workbook cell being locked and sheets being password protected

    Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="Password"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B40").Locked = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password"
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    ' Now the timer has to be reset to unlock the cells
    Dim CurrTime As Date
    Dim UnLockTime As Date

    CurrTime = Time
    UnLockTime = "17:30:00"
    Application.OnTime UnLockTime - CurrTime + Now, "UnLockSheet"

    MsgBox "The cells have been locked"

End Sub


Sub UnLockSheet()

    ' This will unlock the cells

    ' Specify the exact sheet name otherwise whichever sheet is active, will have cells unlocked and a password set
    ' I would also specify the workbook name to prevent any other workbook cells being unlocked and sheets being password protected

    Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="Password"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B40").Locked = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password"
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    MsgBox "The cells have been unlocked"

End Sub
```

If you amend the unlock times then make sure you change the times in both scripts in ThisWorkbook and Module